# Perl6 Exception handling print X::AdHoc message on the CATCH section

Tags: raku

Suppose I have the following code:

```
try {

    X::Any.new(payload => 'Error !',message => "fff").throw;
    #  die "message";

    CATCH {
        #  when X::HTTP { say $_.url(); }    
        when X::AdHoc { say $_; }
    }
}
```

How can I print the message or the payload? I tried the following :

```
say $_.message ;
say $_.payload ;
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: When you call a method on `$_` (`$_.method`) you can shorten it to just `.method`. If you have a Positional or Associative  in `$_`, you can similarly use `.[0]` and `.{'a'}` / `.<a>`. (This only works if the parser is expecting a term, but that is likely how you would expect it to work anyway.) This is similar to `$0` being short for `$/[0]` and `$<a>` being short for `$/<a>` / `$/{'a'}`.

Answer (score 2):

```
X::AdHoc.new(payload=>"anything that got .Str").throw;

CATCH { 
    default {
        printf('"%s", "%s", "%s"', .^name, .payload.^name, .message) 
    }
}

# OUTPUT«"X::AdHoc", "Str", "anything that got .Str"»
```

Comment: are there an option to remove this  :in block <unit> at fille.pl6 from the .message ? as my output add this line to the message : in block <unit> at fille.pl6

Comment: @smith To mark an exception as *handled* a CATCH block must contain a matching `when` statement (which matches specific exceptions) or `default` statement (which matches all remaining exceptions). I've queued an edit to gfldex's answer but in the meantime: `CATCH { default { printf('"%s", "%s", "%s"', .^name, .payload.^name, .message) } }`.

Answer (score 2):

If your interested in a minimalist way...
A CATCH block turns its enclosing block into a try block so the "try { ... }" is redundant.  Within the CATCH block you have an implicit perl6 switch statement with the exception object as the topic.  This is why "when" and "default" keywords can be used.  Finally, exception objects stringify to their message attribute which gives us;

```
CATCH {
   default { .say }
}
```

Replace .say with .payload.say to get the payload.